# Find list of tables inside dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to find list of tables in dynamic query inside stored procedures (and they are quite a few). How can I find them?

**Addition to requirement: Need to extract the database name also along with table name.**

Below is a sample stored procedure and query to find tables inside stored procedure. The query does not return any results.

Please note I cannot alter the stored procedure as its a legacy code.

**My company admin confirmed that we cannot use powershell/.NET scripts as the development/Prod database are on client network and this would violate its security policies.**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.FindTablesInsideDynamicQuery (@companyID int)
as 
begin
DECLARE @dynamicSQL TABLE (id int identity(1,1), line varchar(max))

    insert into @dynamicSQL(line)
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.table1 where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';'
    union
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.Shares where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';'
    union
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.ExtremeGames where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';'
    union
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.Earning where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';'
    union
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.Fortress where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';'
    union
    select 'delete from MCQ.dbo.BlackScholes where companyid = ' + Convert(varchar, @CompanyID) +';' 
end 
GO

declare @spName varchar(100) = 'FindTablesInsideDynamicQuery'

SELECT distinct
referencing_schema_name = SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID),
referencing_object_name = o.name,
referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name,
referenced_object_type_desc = o1.type_desc,
referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name
FROM
sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.objects o1 ON sed.referenced_id = o1.[object_id]
where o.name =  @spName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.sql_modules` to extract the table details from dynamic SQL in stored procedures.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @spName VARCHAR(100)= 'FindTablesInsideDynamicQuery';
DECLARE @objects_used VARCHAR(MAX)= '';
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    WHERE definition LIKE '%' + @spName + '%'
);
WHILE((PATINDEX('%[.][a-z][a-z][a-z][.]%', @str)) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, LEN(@str) - (CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@str), LEN(@str) - (PATINDEX('%[.][a-z][a-z][a-z][.]%', @str))) - 1), LEN(@str));
        SET @objects_used+=SUBSTRING(@str, 1,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@STR)), 1) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@STR)), 1) ELSE LEN(@STR) END);
        SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, (PATINDEX('%[.][a-z][a-z][a-z][.]%', @str) + 1), LEN(@str));
    END;
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@objects_used)), ' ');
```

The above script assumes that the schema name is of three characters in the procedure.

Comment: is it possible to get database name also in along with schema and table name ?

Comment: @Myzus I have updated the answer to include variable length database name as well.